# django-models - a non-string type is stored into CharField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-model-field

I am using Django 1.11 on Python 3, and MySQL 5.7.

Suppose I have a model with a CharField, like so:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):

    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    a = models.CharField()
```

And in the shell, I tried doing this:

```
>>> instance = ModelA(a={'1' : 1})
>>> instance
```

which gives me a TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type dict)

But when I do this:

```
>>> instance.save()
```

I don't get any error.

If I try:

```
>>> instance.a
{'1': 1}
```

But when I try:

```
>>> ModelA.objects.get(ID=<the ID of the above instance>).a
"{'1': 1}"
```

Which means that it got stored in the database table as a string.

My question is why does this implicit conversion happen, and why doesn't save() raise an error like __str__() did?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A model instance is just a python object. You can set any attribute to any value.

When you save the instance, all data is converted to the appropriate data types to Django's best ability. For a CharField this means that any truthy value (str(value) is True) is saved in the database

When you save a model, the current values of the field is read, converted to an appropriate data type, and saved to the database.

```
TypeError: `__str__` returned non-string (type dict)
```

It's because of before conversion. After saving the data Django will be changed the type to `str` so you are not getting an error after saving the instance.

Use [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField) If you want to save the Dict kind of object and make sure you are using Postgres DB.